# Cuando redirecciono con archivo htaccess desaparecen los archivos js/css

Tags: javascript, html, css, .htaccess

estaba intentando crear rutas más amigables para el usuario con el .htaccess y lo he conseguido, el problema es que cuando carga la página, todos sus archivos css y js no se aplican, así que aparece en un texto plano, quisiera saber como solucionar este problema, actualmente tengo el archivo .htaccess así:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^producto/([0-9]+)$ producto.php?id=$1
```

Muhas gracias de antemano a quien pueda ayudarme, mi forma de enlazar los archivos css y javascript lo hago en cada página, por ejemplo:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="js/shop-single.js"></script>
```

Comment: Debes crear rutas absolutas para cargar archivos: css, js, imágenes, otras páginas, etc.

Comment: Me podrías dar un ejemplo?

Comment: Claro, edita la pregunta y agrega un ejemplo de cómo enlazas estilos y javascript.

Comment: Listo, he editado la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongamos que tienes la estructura de tu sitio más o menos así:

```
home
  + - css
  |    - style.css
  + - js
  |    - shop-single.js
  | - index.php
  | - producto.php
```

Antes de las URL amigables accedías con *dominio/producto.php* y no había problema porque tanto CSS como JS están en el mismo nivel y puedes enlazar con *css/style.css*, porque el navegador lo buscará en la raíz del sitio.

Ahora, con las URL amigables accedes con *dominio/producto/ID-PRODUCTO* y el navegador busca a partir de la ruta actual, es decir: *dominio/producto/css.style.css*

Dentro de *producto.php* puedes tratar de enlazar con `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">` diciéndole al navegador que vaya una carpeta atrás (`../`) para buscar el archivo.

¿Pero qué pasa si quieres poner más cosas en la URL, digamos *producto/nombre-categoria/ID-PRODUCTO*? Deberías usar dos veces los dos puntos y la diagonal para decirle al navegador que retroceda 2 carpetas: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/style.css">`

Tarde o temprano llegará el momento en que la estructura de tu sitio crezca tanto que esto se haga poco manejable.

### Solución: URLs absolutas

Cuando agregas una diagonal al inicio de una URL, le indicas al navegador que inicie la búsqueda desde la carpeta raíz del sitio: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">`

El único inconveniente de esto es obligas a que el proyecto esté siempre en la raíz del sitio. Aunque puedes solucionarlo creando una constante en PHP para agregar a cada elemento que necesites, por ejemplo:

Tienes un script PHP que siempre incluyes para obtener conexión a base de datos o iniciar sesiones, etc.

```
// Archivo: funciones.php
// Siempre debe terminar con diagonal
define('RUTA', '/carpeta_proyecto/'); // Puede ser solo '/' para la raíz del sitio

// En tus otros archivos PHP agregas la ruta a los elementos que necesites
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo RUTA; ?>css/style.css">
```

Comment: Y en mi caso, mi proyecto tiene de nombre "Carrito" en el localhost, cuando eso lo pase a un hosting con dominio, como se debería llamar la ruta? Con el nombre del dominio?

Comment: No, en localhost deja _/Carrito/_ y cuando lo subas al servidor solo diagonal _/_